# String comparation strange behavior in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-6

Today I noticed very strange behavior when I compare 2 different strings

```
dd('115e-401' == '115e-402');
```

this is return `true`. But why?;

[image]

Comment: I would guess (without testing) that it is treating these strings as incredibly large numbers because it's assuming that `e-401` is an exponent of the order 401.  Comparing two enormous numbers like this may be beyond what PHP is capable of

Comment: Thank you for explanation

Comment: When using strict comparison (`===`) this is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type juggling kicks in when the strings appear to be numbers.

If both operands are numeric strings, or one operand is a number and the other one is a numeric string, then the comparison is done numerically.

E-401 is a very small number which is smaller than what PHP can represent. The smallest number is `PHP_FLOAT_MIN` about 2.2E-308 (system dependent).

Therefore, your strings are converted to numbers. They are smaller than what PHP can represent and are converted to zero. 0 == 0 is true.

Answer (score 3):

Having quickly tested that the following returns `true` in PHP:

```
var_dump('115e-401' == '115e-402');
```

And then confirmed that this returns `false` (**note the change of `e` to `f`**):

```
var_dump('115f-401' == '115f-402');
```

I can only surmise that the compiler is treating the strings as large exponents and the comparison is too large to calculate correctly (`115e-401` and `115e-402` being ridiculously small numbers). Note: thank you @Tobias K for pointing out the error in stating these were *large* instead of *small* numbers!

If you would like to correctly compare the strings, use a strict type comparison (i.e. `===` or [`strcmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)) instead:

```
var_dump('115e-401' === '115e-402'); // false
var_dump(strcmp("115e-401","115e-402")); // A non-zero value
```

[`strcmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) will return a non-zero value - indicating that they are not equal. A result of 0 would indicate equality in this case.

Note: Clarified that the result of `strcmp` will be non-zero indicating the values are not equal following helpful feedback from @u_mulder.

Comment: The numbers are very small, not very large (negative exponent), but the essence of your answer is true, it goes out of precision.

Comment: @TobiasK. Thank you for the catch there, in my haste I hadn't stopped to think! I've clarified that the numbers are, in fact, very small in the answer now

Comment: `var_dump(strcmp("115e-401","115e-402"));` will return -256: https://3v4l.org/5ktbs

Comment: Not in the PHP compiler I'm testing with here. In fact, I've tested on two different online ones and one gives -1, and one gives -256. A bit odd

Comment: @u_mulder I've modified the answer to reflect that a non-zero answer indicates the strings are different as I can't explain why I'm seeing -1 on one compiler and -256 on another.  However, the fact that only a result of 0 indicates equality is hopefully the primary fact in this case. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: This is UB in C aswell. The only certainty you get is <0, ==0 or >0 - the specific value can be just -1 or actually a "difference range" depending on implementation (I assume PHP simply depends on libc here). Just check those conditions (==0 or !=0), not ==-1. Or use strict `===` to just compare the strings.